# Build a one-page navigation within a non-one-page ttheme…

Tags: menus, user-registration

My theme is not a one-page theme. Nevertheless I would like to have on one page of my site a one-page navigation.

For example:
In primary menu I have "About us", "Responsibility", "Our offer"…
"Responsibility" and "Our Offer" has some sub-navigations points in the drop-down menu. And they are linking to singe pages.

But "About us" should be a one-pager. All the sub-menu points in the drop-down, opening when "About us" is clicked, should not link to different pages, but to the same page but to different sections within this page.

How do I set up this?

Can I build a menu as I would normally do it in the backend. So I drag-and-drop a menu with "About us" and so on. I drag-and-drop some submenu points to "About us" like "History", "Career" and so on. Then I put my content on the "About us" page and add some IDs to my  headings like  as an anchor. 
Then I go to the .php-file in which my just build menu is and link not to different pages but to the corresponding IDs.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do exactly what you suggest. You do not need to create a separate menu or change the php of a page template.

If you add IDs like you suggested as anchors, then your menu items can just specifically target those IDs via the # sign.

To control the link to this degree, you will need to add "Custom links" instead of just selecting the page from the list.

Example Page: (domain.com/about-us/)

Item on example page :  `<h2 id="history">History</h2>`

Menu item: Custom link pointed to domain.com/about-us/#history